# Cannot start Canopy's IPython from Windows command shell

Tags: ipython, enthought

I have been using EPD for some time and recently started using Canopy. So now I have both EPD and Canopy installed on my machine, which runs Windows 7 Pro x64. But I just realized I cannot launch Canopy's IPython interactive session (located in the directory C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts) in a Windows command prompt. I already added this directory to my Path before the EPD's python directory.

I checked out those files in the directory .../Canopy/User/Scripts/, I believe that problem is not with the file "ipython-script.py" there, but with the file "ipython.exe", which is what will be run when I simply type "ipython" in a Windows command shell (I set the path already).

In a Windows command shell, if I changed to the directory .../Canopy/User/Scripts/ and type up "python ipython-script.py", then I can correctly start the IPython session in the command shell. So, it looks like that "ipython.exe" does not run the script "ipython-script.py"...

Has anyone run into this same problem? Is there an easy fix?

P.S. I already had the latest Canopy (version 1.0.1.1160) installed.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you try running `ipython` from the `Canopy command prompt` installed in your *Start Menu*?

Comment: No. Same as at Windows command prompt, nothing happens when I type "ipython" at the Canopy command prompt.

But the IPython embedded in the Canopy integrated code editor works fine. It starts with the code editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch web interactive then the command
`ipython notebook`  in windows shell or in canopy shell works.